# XSLT transform of flat structure to multi-layered nested structure

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am fairly new to XML/XLST processing, and am working in an environment where I must using version 1 processing.  I have an XML file that is exported from an Excel spreadsheet.  The file looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TmData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="10"
Date="2012-11-07T10:11:09.017242-05:00" Format="1" Author="System" Description="Import"
Culture="en-US">
<DocumentElement>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER/>
        <FOLDER1>Management</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2>Human Resources</FOLDER2>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Knowledge and People</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Insufficient investment in training</TITLE>
        <CODE>code001</CODE>
        <RISKCATEGORY1>Securtiy</RISKCATEGORY1>
        <RISKCATEGORY2>Indirect Assertion</RISKCATEGORY2>
        <RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>32.5</RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>
        <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>6</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER/>
        <FOLDER1>Management</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2>Human Resources</FOLDER2>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Knowledge and People</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Over-reliance on one or a few key employees</TITLE>
        <CODE>code002</CODE>
        <RISKCATEGORY3>Securtity</RISKCATEGORY3>
        <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
        <WEIGHT>323.5</WEIGHT>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>7</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER/>
        <FOLDER1>Management</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2>Human Resources</FOLDER2>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Knowledge and People</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Inability to recruit / retain staff</TITLE>
        <CODE>code003</CODE>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>8</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER/>
        <FOLDER1>Management</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2>Human Resources</FOLDER2>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Knowledge and People</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Unexpected / unbudgeted cost increases</TITLE>
        <CODE>code004</CODE>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>9</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER/>
        <FOLDER1>Management</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2>Financial</FOLDER2>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Financial Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Failure to achieve margins</TITLE>
        <CODE>code005</CODE>
        <RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>232.5</RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>
        <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>12</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER/>
        <FOLDER1>Management</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2>Financial</FOLDER2>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Financial Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Adverse impact of exchange rate fluctuations</TITLE>
        <CODE>code006</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>13</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1/>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Strategic / Vision</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Strategy is not implemented</TITLE>
        <CODE>code008</CODE>
        <RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>0</RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>
        <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
        <WEIGHT>10000000000.58</WEIGHT>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>16</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1/>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Strategic / Vision</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Failure to have and execute R&amp;D plans</TITLE>
        <CODE>code009</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>17</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1/>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Strategic / Vision</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Risk management practices do not exist</TITLE>
        <CODE>code010</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>18</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1>Environment</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Environment Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Community involvement objectives are not clearly articulated</TITLE>
        <CODE>code011</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>21</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1>Environment</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Environment Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Time off for community involvement is no adequately controlled</TITLE>
        <CODE>code012</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>22</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1>Market</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Market Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Brand / reputation damage by company environmental failure</TITLE>
        <CODE>Ad.358</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>25</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1>Market</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Market Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Supply of raw materials affected by environmental failure</TITLE>
        <CODE>CK.324</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>26</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1>Market</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Market Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Loss of business through unattractive product / service offerings</TITLE>
        <CODE>AABB01</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>27</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
    <Risks>
        <FOLDER>ACME Manufacturing</FOLDER>
        <FOLDER1>Market</FOLDER1>
        <FOLDER2/>
        <RISK_x0020_FOLDER>Market Div</RISK_x0020_FOLDER>
        <TITLE>Natural disaster</TITLE>
        <CODE>CCDD03</CODE>
        <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
        <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
        <_SheetName>C:\Users\Hugh.Manning\AppData\Local\Temp\CDEA67E1F7034E89B86DD770700A7B19\82F56919D18640DA9EC54FE569B6A3F8.xls
            [Risks]</_SheetName>
        <_RowNumber>28</_RowNumber>
    </Risks>
</DocumentElement>
</TmData>
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TmData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
Version="10"
Date="2012-10-31T09:35:28.9068981-04:00" Format="1" Author="System" Description="Import"
Culture="en-US"><FOLDERS>
<FOLDER>
  <Title/>
  <FOLDERS>
    <FOLDER>
      <Title>Management</Title>
      <FOLDERS>
        <FOLDER>
          <Title>Human Resources</Title>
          <FOLDERS>
            <FOLDER>
              <Title>Knowledge and People</Title>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Insufficient investment in training</TITLE>
                <CODE>code001</CODE>
                <RISKCATEGORY1>Security</RISKCATEGORY1>
                <RISKCATEGORY2>Indirect Assertion</RISKCATEGORY2>
                <RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>32.5</RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>
                <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Over-reliance on one or a few key employees</TITLE>
                <CODE>code002</CODE>
                <RISKCATEGORY3>Security</RISKCATEGORY3>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Inability to recruit / retain staff</TITLE>
                <CODE>code003</CODE>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>
                  Unexpected / unbudgeted cost
                  increases
                </TITLE>
                <CODE>code004</CODE>
              </Risk>
            </FOLDER>
          </FOLDERS>
        </FOLDER>
        <FOLDER>
          <Title>Financial</Title>
          <FOLDERS>
            <FOLDER>
              <Title>Financial Div</Title>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Failure to achieve margins</TITLE>
                <CODE>code005</CODE>
                <RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>232.5</RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>
                <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>
                  Adverse impact of exchange rate
                  fluctuations
                </TITLE>
                <CODE>code006</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
              </Risk>
            </FOLDER>
          </FOLDERS>
        </FOLDER>
      </FOLDERS>
    </FOLDER>
  </FOLDERS>
</FOLDER>
<FOLDER>
  <Title>ACME Manufacturing</Title>
  <FOLDERS>
    <FOLDER>
      <Title/>
      <FOLDERS>
        <FOLDER>
          <Title/>
          <FOLDERS>
            <FOLDER>
              <Title>Strategic / Vision</Title>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Strategy is not implemented</TITLE>
                <CODE>code008</CODE>
                <RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>0</RISKNUMBERICVALUE1>
                <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
                <WEIGHT>10000000000.58</WEIGHT>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Failure to have and execute R&amp;D plans</TITLE>
                <CODE>code009</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Risk management practices do not exist</TITLE>
                <CODE>code010</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>1</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
            </FOLDER>
          </FOLDERS>
        </FOLDER>
      </FOLDERS>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER>
      <Title>Environment</Title>
      <FOLDERS>
        <FOLDER>
          <Title/>
          <FOLDERS>
            <FOLDER>
              <Title>Environment Div</Title>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>
                  Community involvement objectives are not
                  clearly articulated
                </TITLE>
                <CODE>code011</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>
                  Time off for community involvement is no
                  adequately controlled
                </TITLE>
                <CODE>code012</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>0</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
            </FOLDER>
          </FOLDERS>
        </FOLDER>
      </FOLDERS>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER>
      <Title>Market</Title>
      <FOLDERS>
        <FOLDER>
          <Title/>
          <FOLDERS>
            <FOLDER>
              <Title>Market Div</Title>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>
                  Brand / reputation damage by company
                  environmental failure
                </TITLE>
                <CODE>Ad.358</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>
                  Supply of raw materials affected by
                  environmental failure
                </TITLE>
                <CODE>CK.324</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>
                  Loss of business through unattractive
                  product / service offerings
                </TITLE>
                <CODE>AABB01</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Natural disaster</TITLE>
                <CODE>CCDD03</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
            </FOLDER>
            <FOLDER>
              <Title>Sales Div</Title>
              <Risk>
                <TITLE>Failure to achieve sales quota</TITLE>
                <CODE>S.001</CODE>
                <RISKYESNO1>0</RISKYESNO1>
                <RISKYESNO2>1</RISKYESNO2>
              </Risk>
            </FOLDER>
          </FOLDERS>
        </FOLDER>
      </FOLDERS>
    </FOLDER>
  </FOLDERS>
</FOLDER>
</FOLDERS>
</TmData>
```

I have worked up the following XSLT file that will get me most of the way there, but I cannot figure out how to prevent the duplication of the FLODERS nodes.  The XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="rowSelector" select="local-name(//DocumentElement/*[1])"/>   

<xsl:template match="/TmData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DocumentElement"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DocumentElement">
    <FOLDERS>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="Elements"/>
    </FOLDERS>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Risks">       
  <xsl:apply-templates />      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(name(),'_'))">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RISK_x0020_FOLDER">
    <FOLDER>
        <Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Title>        
        <xsl:call-template name="RiskTemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="RiskFolderName" select ="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </FOLDER>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="FOLDER |FOLDER1 |FOLDER2 |FOLDER3">
    <xsl:param name="folderName"/>
    <xsl:param name="folderValue"/>
    <FOLDER>
        <Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Title>
        <FOLDERS>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(local-name(following-sibling::*[1]),'FOLDER')">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>                        
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(local-name(following-sibling::*[1]),'RISK_x')">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            </FOLDERS>
    </FOLDER>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="RiskTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="RiskFolderName"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Risks[RISK_x0020_FOLDER=$RiskFolderName]">
        <Risk>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TITLE"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CODE"/>            
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TYPE"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DESCRIPTION"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="NOTES"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKCATEGORY1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKCATEGORY2"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKCATEGORY3"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKCATEGORY4"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKMULTISELECTCATEGORY"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKNUMBERICVALUE1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKYESNO1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RISKYESNO2"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="WEIGHT"/>
        </Risk>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="Elements">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = $rowSelector">
            <xsl:call-template name="Risks"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get from the transformation has the first block being correct with nesting, but I cannot figure out how to prevent the transform from looking at nodes it has already processed.  There is a great deal of duplication, which is what I am trying to eliminate.  I have been trying to figure this out for over a week now, and could really use some help.  Thanks in advance to all the XML/XSLT gurus out there.

Answer (score 1):

This template should solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!--
    Initial template.
    -->
  <xsl:template match="/TmData">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="folders">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="risks" select="DocumentElement/Risks"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
    This template is applied to <Risks/>, once the folder for the risk
    has been built.
    -->
  <xsl:template match="Risks" mode="folder-content">
    <Risk>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|element()[not(starts-with(local-name(), '_') or contains(local-name(), 'FOLDER'))]"/>
    </Risk>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
    Called to build out the folders at a given depth.
    params:
      depth: the current folder depth.
      risks: the risks that are in this folder.
    -->
  <xsl:template name="folders">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:param name="risks"/>
    <FOLDERS>
      <xsl:call-template name="folder">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="risks" select="$risks"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </FOLDERS>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
    Called to build a folder.  This template builds the folder for the first risk
    in the risks parameter.  It then creates the nested folders for that risk, by
    calling the folders template with the risks that are in the folder.  Finally,
    the template creates more folders at the same depth, by calling itself with
    the risks that were not in this folder.

    params:
      depth: the current folder depth.
      risks: the risks that are in this folder.
    -->
  <xsl:template name="folder">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:param name="risks"/>
    <xsl:if test="$risks">
      <xsl:variable name="element-name">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$depth=0">FOLDER</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$risks[1]/*[local-name()=concat('FOLDER', $depth)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('FOLDER', $depth)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>RISK_x0020_FOLDER</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>

      <!-- Build the folder for $risks[1] -->
      <FOLDER>
        <TITLE>
          <xsl:value-of select="$risks[1]/*[local-name()=$element-name]"/>
        </TITLE>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$element-name='RISK_x0020_FOLDER'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$risks" mode="folder-content"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Build nested folders for all of the risks in the same folder as $risks[1]. -->
            <xsl:call-template name="folders">
              <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="risks" select="$risks[*[local-name()=$element-name]=$risks[1]/*[local-name()=$element-name]]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </FOLDER>

      <!-- Build sibling folders for the risks that are not in the same folder as $risks[1] -->
      <xsl:call-template name="folder">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="risks"
          select="$risks[not(*[local-name()=$element-name]=$risks[1]/*[local-name()=$element-name])]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For cases like this, I would avoid applying templates.  It is a lot easier to create a set of the things to be processed and then use recursive call templates to do the processing.